# javascript/css: Make image expand up and to left on rollover effect

Tags: javascript, css, image, rollover

I want to let users expand thumbnail to see large profile pic on mouseover.  However, the rollover effect I have currently expands the table row to the size of the expanded image rather than showing the image over the surrounding text.  Can anyone suggest a way to expand images on rollover without moving text around, in other words showing larger image on top of other html rather than pushing it out of way.  I have tried z-index and this does not seem to work.

Here is a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/gLr9Q/

Here is same code as in js fiddle:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  <!-- hide from non JavaScript Browsers
  image = new Array()
  image[0]= new Image(24,24)
  image[0].src = "http://womeninbiznetwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/logo-google.thumbnail.gif"
  image[1] = new Image(48,48)
  image[1].src = "https://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif"
</script>
<tr><td colspan=2>
<p align="center"> 
<a href="contactdetail.php"
  onmouseover="newPic()"
  onmouseout="oldPic()">
<img src="http://womeninbiznetwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/logo-google.thumbnail.gif"
  name="pic" 
class="rollover"  
    border=0>
</a> 
</p></td></tr>
<tr><td>Here is text</td></tr>
```

js

```
function newPic(){
    document.pic.style.left="-24px";
    document.pic.style.top="-24px";
     document.pic.src = image[1].src;
    return true;
  }

  function oldPic(){
    document.pic.src = image[0].src; 
    return true;
  }
```

css:

```
#rollover {
  display: block;
  z-index:99;
  padding: 4px;
  position:relative;
  text-align:left;
  width:48px;
  background-color:#E8E8E8;
  opacity:1.0;
  filter:alpha(opacity=100); 
}
```

Comment: You're probably going to want to clone the element and position it absolutely based on the location of the thumbnail.

Comment: No need to clone it and it's actually possible with only CSS and :hover. It requires the images container to have a given width and height though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stolen from [CSSplay - magnify](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/magnify.html), you can do this without Javascript

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan=2>
        <p align="center">  <a class="rollover" href="contactdetail.php">
            <img src="http://womeninbiznetwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/logo-google.thumbnail.gif" name="pic" border="0"/>
            <span><img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif"/></span>
</a> 
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Here is text</td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
a.rollover {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
a.rollover span {
    position: absolute;
    left: -10000px;
}
a.rollover:hover span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLr9Q/5/)

**Update**:

I don't know, if this is what you have in mind, but you can position the larger image anywhere you want

CSS:

```
a.rollover:hover span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 120px;
    top: -20px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLr9Q/7/)

If you want to hide the lower image on hover, you can try adding `opacity: 0`

```
<img class="thumbnail" src="...">
```

and

```
a.rollover:hover .thumbnail {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLr9Q/8/)

Although, I don't know if this works on every browser.

Comment: This looks pretty good.  IS there a way to anchor the lower right hand corner and have it expand up and to left?

Comment: Got this to work.  Like the simplicity.  Just in case different browsers render differently, is there anyway in CSS to make behind image disappear...It took a bit of adjustment to get new image to exactly cover old one and I'm concerned people with different font sizes selected or different browsers might see part of below image peaking out one one side or another...

Comment: @user1904273 You can try `opacity: 0` on the below image. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add something like this:

```
#Text {
    position:absolute;
    top:48px;
}
```

where your text is in a block element with ID `Text`. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLr9Q/2/).

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question of expanding the image.

Comment: Look at the Fiddle I linked to. I believe that's what the OP was looking for, unless I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this is to clone all the `<img>` nodes you want, put them inside `<div>`s and then use CSS's [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3ahover) to do the rest of the work for you. [**example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BysCN/).
My code will work for as many `<img>`s as you like, anywhere in the document and does not require fixed sizes of parent nodes.
You may need to modify your CSS or the class names I've chosen if other styles aren't as you expected due to the changes to HTML structure by the JavaScript (see "Resulting HTML" below).

```
// JavaScript
window.onload = function () { // when document has loaded, consider `window.addEventListener('load', /* code */, false);` in real world usage
    var elm = document.querySelectorAll('img.rollover'), // get all <img>s with class "rollover"
        i = elm.length, d;
    while (--i >= 0) { // put each one and a clone into a <div> where it was
        d = elm[i].parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement('div'), elm[i]);
        d.className = 'rollover';
        elm[i].className = (' '+elm[i].className+' ') // set class'
                            .replace(/ rollover /g, ' ')
                            .slice(1, -1);
        d.appendChild(elm[i]);
        d.appendChild(elm[i].cloneNode()).className += ' rollover_big'; // I did clone here to save needing an extra variable
        elm[i].className += ' rollover_small';
    }
};

/* CSS */
div.rollover {position: relative; display: block;} /* relative to allow for abs. positioning of big image */
div.rollover img.rollover_small {width: 24px;}
div.rollover img.rollover_big { /* position over small image*/
    width: 48px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}

div.rollover:hover img.rollover_small {visibility: hidden;} /* visibility to hold space*/
div.rollover:hover img.rollover_big {display: block;} /* show bigger node*/

<!-- HTML -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2><a href="contactdetail.php"><img src="http://womeninbiznetwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/logo-google.thumbnail.gif" class="rollover"/></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Here is text</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- etc. -->
</table>

<!-- Resulting HTML after load event -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2><a href="contactdetail.php">
            <div class="rollover">
                <img src="http://womeninbiznetwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/logo-google.thumbnail.gif" class="rollover_small"/>
                <img src="http://womeninbiznetwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/logo-google.thumbnail.gif" class="rollover_big"/>
            </div>
        </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Here is text</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- etc. -->
</table>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the image expand up and to the left?  I think this would look better than having it expand dowwnard

Comment: @user1904273 yep, in `div.rollover img.rollover_big` (css) set `top: -12px; left: -12px;` or however you want it.

Comment: You can even position with `bottom: 0; right: 0;` or percentages. The image is in it's own block element so any absolute positioning is calculated from that and not from the edges of the document.

Comment: Use bottom right as Paul S. mentioned. That's the easiest and cleanest way.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need javascript for this.  See the **[working demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/onury/YM6Am/)**.
Do it with **CSS**:

```
td.imgCell {
    height: 40px; /* a value greater than image height + paddings */
    text-align: center;
}

img.rollover {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color:#E8E8E8;
    border: 0px none;
}

img.rollover:hover {
    position: absolute;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    margin-top: -24px;
    margin-left: -24px;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Here is the modified **HTML**:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="imgCell">
            <a href="contactdetail.php">
                <img class="rollover" src="http://womeninbiznetwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/logo-google.thumbnail.gif" />
            </a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Here is text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Notice that a class for the container td is also declared and set: `<td class="imgCell">`

**Key points:**

- The container `<td>` should have a fixed height.
- The image should have `absolute` position when hovered.

**Other Corrections / Suggestions:**

- You don't need the `colspan` attribute there in your HTML. The
  colspan attribute defines the number of columns a cell should span.
  You don't have to do that since you have a single `<td>` in each row
  (`<tr>`).
- You don't really need the wrapping `<p>` tag around your anchor tag. But it's not wrong.

If you insist on using that JS code;

- You should also include `//-->` right before the `</script>` tag
  since you have `<!-- hide from non JavaScript Browsers` in the
  begining.
- You should add semicolons at the end of each javascript statement.
  You have none.
- You should declare the image variable with a `var`, or otherwise it
  will be in the global scope.
- You should initialize the array with `[]` instead of `new Array()` as
  tools like jsLint suggest.